# Selenium: clean way to iterate of list of WebElements who become stale during the iteration

Tags: selenium, exception

This is my code:

```
foreach(IWebElement close in el.FindElements(By.ClassName("search-choice-close")))
{
    close.Click();
    TestHelper.WaitForAjaxCompletion(d);
}
```

The elements listed in `FindElements` are all list items in a "multiselect" (a `select` that's hidden behind a fancy `ul/li` javascript widget.

When the loop enters the second time, I get a `StaleElementException`, because clicking the first element updates the DOM.

What is a clean way to loop nicely over these elements that, I assume, must be 'found' after each DOM update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a helper function to see if at least one element still exists.
Because I'm finding a new element each loop, `StaleElementException` doesn't occur anymore.

```
while(isElementVisible(d, (By.ClassName("search-choice-close"))))
{
    d.FindElement(By.ClassName("search-choice-close")).Click();
    TestHelper.WaitForAjaxCompletion(d);
}
```